# HttpClient results in predictable exceptions

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am using .NET 4.0 to try to leverage the functionality provided by HttpClient. The aim is to upload a particular file around 10.5 MB in size to a remote server using HTTP Verb "PUT". The remote server uses node.js.

I have written a small Console app (.NET 4.0 full not client profile)
The laptop I am using does not has .NET 4.5 or Visual Studio 2012
I installed  Added these NuGet packages onto it to enable Async    upload features with progress update

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40-Client" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

I then wrote a simple function that does a synchronous upload (UploadFile). This function works as expected and uploads the files correctly.

The next method called UploadFileAsync tries to use HttpClient and fails between 55-70% of upload. Visual Studio 2010 throws up a series of exceptions. The first one is usually different ranging from

```
WebException
"The request was aborted: The request was cancelled"
```

to various other types. The second exception however is always predictable and same. This is

```
ObjectDisposedExceptoin
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
```

Finally this is the last exception in the chain

```
IOException

    Unable to read data from the transport connection: Cannot access a disposed object.
    Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'..
```

As you would notice I have removed all using blocks, close or dispose statements etc. from my code. For the life of me I can not figure out what is going wrong! I have tried PutAsync, and SendAsnyc methods both with HttpClient. The only difference they make is that the first exception changes.

Here is the code block

```
void UploadFile(string fileToUpload)
        {
            //string fileToUpload = @"F:\\upload_file.txt";
            using (FileStream rdr = new FileStream(fileToUpload, FileMode.Open))
            {
                HttpWebRequest req = null;
                Stream reqStream = null;
                try
                {
                    req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                    req.Method = "PUT";
                    req.Headers.Add("x-myheader", "163333.zip");
                    req.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                    req.ContentLength = rdr.Length;
                    req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
                    req.Timeout = 1000000;
                    reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
                    Console.WriteLine(rdr.Length);
                    byte[] inData = new byte[rdr.Length];

                    // Get data from upload file to inData 
                    int bytesRead = rdr.Read(inData, 0, (int)rdr.Length);

                    // put data into request stream
                    reqStream.Write(inData, 0, (int)rdr.Length);
                    rdr.Close();

                    req.GetResponse();
                    // after uploading close stream 
                    reqStream.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    rdr.Close();

                    req.GetResponse();
                    // after uploading close stream 
                    reqStream.Close();

                }
            }


        }



        void UploadFileAsync(string fileToUpload)
        {


            //string fileToUpload = @"F:\\upload_file.txt";
            FileStream rdr = new FileStream(fileToUpload, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 8192, true);
            //newfs rdr = new newfs(fileToUpload, FileMode.Open);
            HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            ProgressMessageHandler progressHandler = new ProgressMessageHandler(clientHandler);
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(progressHandler);

            try
            {


                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-myheader", "163333.zip");

                HttpRequestMessage requestPayLoad = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, url);

                long totalFileSize = rdr.Length;
                Console.WriteLine(totalFileSize);

                int? previousPercentage = null;

                progressHandler.HttpSendProgress += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    if (!previousPercentage.HasValue || previousPercentage != args.ProgressPercentage)
                        Console.WriteLine(args.ProgressPercentage);
                    previousPercentage = args.ProgressPercentage;

                };

                requestPayLoad.Content = new StreamContent(rdr);

                //requestPayLoad.Content = new FileContent(fileToUpload);
                //var task = client.PutAsync<byte[]>(url, rdr, new BinaryMediaTypeFormatter());
                var task = client.SendAsync(requestPayLoad);
                task.Wait();


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                //rdr.Close();
                client.Dispose();
                //req.GetResponse();
                //// after uploading close stream 
                //reqStream.Close();

            }

        }
```

**Update**

It appears that the file does reach the server OK. Which then basically means that the ProgressHandler is reporting incorrect percentages and the error comes at the very right end of the upload. Fiddler shows HTTP 200 status code.

Comment: Try check MaxRequestContentBufferSize property of your HttpClientHandler and enlarge it if it is too small.

Comment: Thanks Vladmir I will try that on Monday. However looking at MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxrequestcontentbuffersize.aspx the default value is 2GB and the file I am uploading is only about 10MB so I am not too sure if that would help. But will give it a go

Comment: No that didn't work either. I am at my wits ends trying to understand this problem.